# 100 > 100 gives true

Tags: php, laravel

I have this object:

```
{
    timestamp:2021-09-10T08:30:00Z,
    keys:[
        {usage_point_id:24329232979894,key:69},
        {usage_point_id:24327496366232,key:7.4},
        {usage_point_id:30002431659877,key:0},
        {usage_point_id:24348769886471,key:1.3755},
        {usage_point_id:24328075237474,key:10.4},
        {usage_point_id:24348480450805,key:11.8245}
    ]
}
```

I want to make sure that the sum of all those percent is not superior to 100. So, I do:

```
$measuresByTS->each(function ($measures) {
    if ($measures['keys']->sum('key') > 100) {
        dump("sum is superior to 100 : ". $measures['keys']->sum('key'));
    }
});
```

Weird thing is in my case, I manually checked the sum and it is equal to 100, not superior. In this case, in my code, it will display:

```
"sum is superior to 100 : 100"
```

I tried to cast `$measures['keys']->sum('key')` to `float`, but it is not working.

Anybody knows why this is happening ?

Using Laravel 8 / PHP 8

Comment: `ini_set('precision', 15); echo (69 + 7.4 + 0 + 1.3755 + 10.4 + 11.8245);`
 results in `100.000000000000014210854715202`

Comment: Like ceejayoz said, this is a rounding problem, use round() to get the correct result.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php ...

Comment: @ceejayoz I thought this woudl be it too but I cannot get that result or anything other than `100` ?? Locally or on eval https://3v4l.org/AbMmh

Comment: There's even 13 digits until the offset becomes obvious.

Comment: Thanks, I rounded to 8 decimals my result and it worked like a charm !

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did it in Laravel's tinker, PHP 8. https://i.stack.imgur.com/joXLO.png Max precision can vary from system to system, IIRC.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You apparently need at least [17 digits](https://3v4l.org/14hiX).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Ah, thanks for that